# Place inner html content in multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to place the value of checkbox in inner HTML and in multiple DIVS. Seems like the code I have isn't working.

```
const ids = ['acc-title-placeholder-3', 'acc-title-placeholder-4', 'acc-title-placeholder-5'];
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(ids.map(id => `#${id}`).join(', '));
    var a = cb.checked ? cb.value : ' ';
    document.querySelectorAll(elements).innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: `elements.forEach(elem => elem.innerHTML = 'foo');`

Comment: I am trying to place the value of checkbox

Comment: so you do what you did with `a`, I just used a random string

Comment: This works, thank you. I just replaced the 'foo' with = cb.value and It populates the value of the radio being selected